# Find maximum number in column and add one (Access & VB.NET)

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, vb.net-2010

The following is my code:

**Page Load**

```
Private Sub frm_addproduct_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        txt_id.Text = generate_id()
    End Sub
```

**Generate ID**

```
Private Function generate_id() As String
        Dim lastid As String = run_sql_query("SELECT MAX(FLD_PRODUCT_ID) AS LASTID FROM TBL_PRODUCTS").Rows(0).Item("LASTID")
        'MsgBox(lastid)
        Dim newid As String = "" & Mid(lastid, 2) + 1
        Return newid
    End Function
```

My problem is that when it displays the id inside the txt_id textbox, and for example the last id is **45** it only shows "6" when it supposed to be "46". What is missing from here?

Comment: This code is not VBA.  Do you mean VB.NET ?

Comment: Using `SELECT MAX(FLD_PRODUCT_ID) + 1 AS NEWID FROM TBL_PRODUCTS` might be easier

Comment: @TimWilliams can you give me a full example on that part of code? Then i should just return **lastid**?

Comment: @TimWilliams Nevermind. i got it already. can you post it as an answer? Thanks! :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Dim lastId as string = "SELECT MAX(FLD_PRODUCT_ID)+1 FROM tablename. . . .";
Return lastId`

Or if the database requires an int, you may convert it as well.

Comment: Isn't is supposed to be `"SELECT MAX(FLD_PRODUCT_ID) + 1 AS LASTID FROM tablename. . . .";`

because if i didn't put **AS LASTID** it won't display anything in the textbox.

Comment: That's a demo. :) The +1 is what really mattered anyway.

Comment: true. but i want it to be displayed in the textbox later on as i wrote in my question. but thanks anyway! :D